# Can't read proguard.ClassPathEntry unexpected EOF

Tags: android, proguard, android-source

I am trying to build cubieboard 4 AOSP source (version 4.4. I think it has nothing to do with Cubieboard). But I am getting errors related to proguard: `Error: Can't read [proguard.ClassPathEntry@5f893efe] (unexpected EOF)
build/core/java.mk:435: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Camera2_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar' failed`

In fact I was able to build complete source without errors previously. But don't know all of a sudden how come this error started appearing.

I have gone through link [Android Proguard java.io.IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884456/android-proguard-java-io-ioexception-cant-read-proguard-classpathentry), though this is related to file not found and mine is unexpected EOF (End of file); and have already tried below things:

- Deleting complete out folder and then doing `$make -j4`
- sourcing envsetup.sh `$. build/envsetup.sh`
- Replacing original proguard tool(4.7) with latest (5.3.1)

I can comment particular PRODUCT_PACKAGES from /build/target/product/sdk.mk etc for which proguard error was coming. But finally came across error for `Camera2` which is absolutely needed for my application and cannot be commented.

Anybody came across this and found solution? Please Help!

**DETAILED LOG with proguard 5.3.1:**

```
Reading library jar [/home/osboxes/Project/Semapresence/cc-a80/android-fresh/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar]  
Reading library jar [/home/osboxes/Project/Semapresence/cc-a80/android-fresh/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar]  
Error: Can't read [/home/osboxes/Project/Semapresence/cc-a80/android-fresh/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar] (unexpected EOF)  
Error: Can't read [/home/osboxes/Project/Semapresence/cc-a80/android-fresh/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar] (unexpected EOF)  
build/core/java.mk:435: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/DeskClock_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar' failed  
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/DeskClock_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar] Error 1  
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....  
build/core/java.mk:435: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Camera2_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar' failed  
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Camera2_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Hope it can help other who faced similar issue:
I could temporarily solve my problem by disabling proguard for particular module for which it was giving error.
To do this added below line to Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
```